# Android Google Analytics API v4 vs v3 Difference

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Can anyone tell me why in `Google Analytics` sample they didn't use `app_tracker.xml` configuration. although it was used in old version of analytics v3. I tried the v4 analytics without `app_tracker.xml` and it works fine without any trouble what is the big deal about it? (and i am noob in analytics)

and in their sample they used following line in Application class. if we define property id in global_tracker.xml why do we need this line or why do we need to configure in the global tracker?

```
private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXXX-Y";
```

Answer (score 1):

They "sort of" do.

I'm not sure how to answer this, but `app_tracker.xml` is just a configuration file, like the `global_tracker.xml`. It is not needed unless you specifically want to define your settings in `xml`.

From [Google Analytics v4 Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/):

> Configuration settings can be managed using resources defined in XML.
>   **For example**, if you have a global tracker you could create a file
>   called global_tracker.xml in your project's res/xml directory and add
>   the following resources:

It is simply an example, and you decide yourself if you want `app_tracker.xml` defines aswell.

To answer your second question regarding the `PROPERTY_ID` I quote the [Google Analytics v4 Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) again:

> Note that the tracker can be created from a PROPERTY_ID using
>   analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID) or it can be created from a xml
>   resource file as analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker).

Hope this clear things up. Happy coding and analyzing :)